# How do I organise 3rd and 4th level navigation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm attempting to structure multiple levels of site navigation by using the "Modify Navigation" setting (Site Actions > Site Settings > Modify Navigation)

But it seems the UI on that page doesn't let me create pages which are children of other pages, or create folders which are children of other folders.

Basically, I need to create not just first level/second level nesting, but also 3rd and 4th level nesting of pages

I understand the parameters to so in the default.master to control if other levels are displayed, but I can't figure out how to create such a structure in sharepoint?

Am I completely missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, there are no "sub-pages" in navigation in MOSS. The nested navigation which Heather Solomon describes in [this article](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/05/15/SharePoint-Tip--How-to-Activate-the-Drop-Down-Menu.aspx) is about how you create multi-level navigation of a known site/subsite hierarchy.

If you need pages and sub-pages in your navigation, you will have to create a custom editor which allows you to define the needed hierarchy, as well as you will have to create a custom "navigation provider" which knows how to navigate the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks!  It appears by using Sites/Subsites/Folders/Pages I can simulate what I need, not sure of the trade offs tho.

Comment: This pattern works quite good and you always get the possibility to customize, for instance, user rights assignments for some of the subsites.